# Permissions Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, permissions, hard-drive

Installing second HDD on 20.04 desktop the HDD originally of Windows O/S. Used Gparted to modify to Ext3. Denies operation due to ROOT only permission. Am rather gunshy with regards to SUDO and CHMOD and CHOWN.
Would appreciate exact syntax to open permission for second HDD.

Comment: I can offer the idea of reading this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1316408/1157519 Might be useful.

Comment: Actually, this answer (on the same question) seems to contain even more specifics: https://askubuntu.com/a/1316328/1157519

Comment: Why ext3 it is usually 4.

Comment: You may want to read this article. https://opensource.com/article/18/4/ext4-filesystem#:~:text=Ext4%20is%20functionally%20very%20similar,higher%20performance%2C%20and%20improved%20timestamps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lubuntu 20.04 denies my own hard disk partition any access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316277/lubuntu-20-04-denies-my-own-hard-disk-partition-any-access)